# Search in Ldap.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

I am trying to use the search method of Ldap.js in my node.js code. But it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
searchFunc : function (){
            console.log('inside search');
            client.bind('cn=Manager,dc=foo,dc=com', kredito231, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    client.unbind();
                    return;
                }

                var opts = {
                    filter: (('Email=*@foo.com'))
                } ;
                 //This search works correct:
                //client.search( 'cn=x,ou=users' + ',' + 'dc=foo,dc=com', function(err,res){
                //This one doesn't work. But everything is done according api
                client.search('dc=foo,dc=com', opts, function(err, res) {
                    res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
                        console.log('hit');
                        console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
                    });
                    res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
                        console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
                    });
                    res.on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log('searchFailed') ;
                        console.error('error: ' + err.message);
                    });
                    res.on('end', function(result) {
                        console.log('4') ;
                        console.log('status: ' + result.status);
                    });
                });

            });

        }
```

When I use the search method by with `dn name`, it returns the correct object with its attributes (`res.on('searchEntry', function(entry)` part executed, because it can find the record in Ldap). But when I use  `client.search('dc=foo,dc=com', opts, function(err, res)` with opt defined above, it always goes to branch 4: `res.on('end', function(result)` and never returns an error status of 0.

[API documentation of Ldap](http://ldapjs.org/client.html).

Comment: Try to give filter: (&('Email=*@foo.com')).

Answer (score 2):

This does not work for `dc=foo,dc=com` because that entry in the LDAP directory does not have the attribute `Email` and hence your filter does not match. The entry `'cn=x,ou=users,dc=foo,dc=com'` in LDAP directory probably has this attribute which is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the following way we can able to search user data

```
function searchUser() {
    var opts = {
         filter: '(objectClass=*)',  //simple search
        //  filter: '(&(uid=2)(sn=John))',// and search
        // filter: '(|(uid=2)(sn=John)(cn=Smith))', // or search
        scope: 'sub',
        attributes: ['sn']
    };

    client.search('ou=users,ou=system', opts, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in search " + err)
        } else {
            res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
            });
            res.on('searchReference', function (referral) {
                console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
            });
            res.on('error', function (err) {
                console.error('error: ' + err.message);
            });
            res.on('end', function (result) {
                console.log('status: ' + result.status);
            });
        }
    });
}
```